# Simple clock showing ascendant numbers

Tags: java, android, xml

I´m just trying to figure out how to show an ascendant number in a text field.

So I tried this, and it compiles but crash quickly xd.

My activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/padre"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
android:id="@+id/mytextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int cont=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer timer=new Timer();

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            update();
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 100, 1000);
}
public void  update() {
    TextView campoTexto=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
    campoTexto.setText(cont);
    cont++;
}
}
```

Comment: post log with exception that caused the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int cont = 0;
    private TextView campoTexto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        campoTexto = findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getBaseContext().getMainLooper());

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mainHandler.post(MainActivity.this::update);
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 100, 1000);
    }

    @MainThread
    public void update() {
        campoTexto.setText(String.valueOf(cont));
        cont++;
    }
}
```

1st problem was that you were using `int` in `campoTexto.setText()` so it was looking for a string with that id.

2nd mistake was changing UI element, in this case `campoTexto` from a background thread.

EDIT:
In order to use my solution you need to enable Java 8 in module(most likely `app` module) level build.gradle file like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

Or you can use this:

```
nHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        update();
    }
});
```

instead of `mainHandler.post(MainActivity.this::update);`

Comment: @OlegarioLópez I edited the answer so you can fix it.

Comment: It was the solution , n1:)

Comment: It would be nice if you could mark it as solved. Do you need any more explanation why does it works or why your doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set integer value to TextView. Integer should be converted to string before setting it to TextView. Use below code to set integer to TextView

```
public void  update() {
    TextView campoTexto=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
    campoTexto.setText(String.valueOf(cont));
    cont++;
}
```